# How to read stdout from script run by system?

Tags: shell-script

I want to debug a script that I placed in `/etc/pm/sleep.d`. In my script I issue an `echo` command to report the status.

Where can I read this output? I'm thinking in something like `dmesg` or a file in `/var/log` maybe?

Is this the better way? What is the standard practice when debugging bash scripts that are supposed to be executed by the system (like those in `/etc/init.d/` or .`Xinit`)?

Comment: Are you sure it even runs?  Pretty much all (recent versions of) today's distos will use systemd for power management not `/etc/pm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that instead of using `echo`, you can use `logger` to output commands to the system log for the purpose of debugging.

```
logger "Oh no"
```

Then, you can check the output in /var/log/syslog

```
sudo tail /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: I didnt know about logger, Thanks for notifying this.

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned , you have an echo statement in your script.

Now edit your script and this like at the beginning of the file after shebang.

```
> /tmp/myoutput
```

myoutput is just a filename in the /tmp mount, you can choose anything you want.

After this , where ever you have echo statement in your script like this

```
echo "something"
```

change it to

```
echo "something" >> /tmp/myoutput
```

that's it, so everytime your script runs, you will have latest track of whats happened with your script.